# MVVM+ WPF PopUp not opening

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, popup

XAML

```
<Popup Name="popUpProgress" Width="225" Height="85"                   
           IsOpen="{Binding PopUpIsOpen,Mode=OneWay}"
           Placement="Center" PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=stkListview}" 
           VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <Border BorderThickness="1" Background="Blue"  >
        <Grid   Width="225" Height="85">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="30" />
                <RowDefinition Height="30" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Label x:Name="lblProgress" Content="Please Wait ...." Margin="10,5,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Row="1" />
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</Popup>
```

In view Model:

```
private bool _PopUpIsOpen;

public bool PopUpIsOpen
{
    get { return _PopUpIsOpen; }
    set
    {
        _PopUpIsOpen = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.PopUpIsOpen);
    }
}

public RelayCommand SubmitCommand { get; private set; }

private bool SubmitCommandCanExecute()
{
    return true;
}

private void SubmitCommandExecute()
{

    PopUpIsOpen = true;

    dsStandardListbyMarket = marketBL.StandardListbyMarketBL(Convert.ToInt32(SelectdMarketId), Convert.ToInt32(Users.UserId));
    GetComboboxMappingCollections(Convert.ToInt32(this.SelectdMarketId), Users.UserId);
    FItems = new ObservableCollection<MarketRecord.FItem>();
    FItems.CollectionChanged += OnUICollectionChanged;
    marketBL.FetchMarketRecords(Convert.ToInt32(this.SelectdMarketId));
    IsSubmitButtonVisible = true;

    PopUpIsOpen = false;
}
```

When I click on submit button control comes to `SubmitCommandExecute` but `Popup` window is not showing. I am bit new to WPF, scratching my head over it. Finally raising this question here. What might be wrong.

Comment: Have you checked the Output window in Visual Studio during runtime? Are there any binding errors? If you manually set the `IsOpen="true"` in XAML does your Popup properly shown?

Comment: You are pausing the UI thread son you can't see the popup shown. Did you try to remove the PopUpIsOpen = false, just to see if it works ?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is in the way you are testing the code. SInce you are sleeping in the UI thread, the UI does not feel the change from true to false on the bound property.
Try to use a timer instead of a Sleep in the thread.

Comment: I accept your answer . If I remove PopUpIsOpen = false after sleep it shows me pop up . But If I call business logic also it is not showing it it comes back from business logic . why so ?That time I am not pausing UI thread right?>

Comment: You should have your business logic working in its own thread, as for example a background worker. I guess you are using caliburn ( am I wrong? =, try to use a coroutine to drive your computation.

Comment: I have updated my question > i already tried with back ground worker . I gives me exception because of  FItems.CollectionChanged += OnUICollectionChanged; this like of code . When this call goes to another thread it throws exception !

Comment: It is normal, you should read about how to use Dispatcher.Invoke in order to marshal from worker thread to UI

Comment: No , its not only about UI . I have  marketBL.AppDataModel.items.CollectionChanged += OnAppModelCollectionChanged; defined in my view model constructor . So when i call marketBL.FetchMarketRecords(Convert.ToInt32(this.SelectdMarketId)); in submit command . It updates my business layer collection which rumns in separate thread . Even that gives me exception . I can hadle UI stuffs with dispatcher. Invoke But what can I do it for business logic collection changed ?

Answer (score -2):

Given the RaisePropertyChanged syntaxe on msdn :

```
protected internal void RaisePropertyChanged (
   string propertyName
)
```

You should try `RaisePropertyChanged("PopUpIsOpen");` instead of `RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.PopUpIsOpen);`

Comment: the OP is probably using some MVVM engine that allow this syntactical sugar.